# What is the difference between a stochastic process and a random variable taking value in a function space?

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables, random

Consider the probability space $(S,\mathcal{A}, P)$. Let $Y$ be a $(\mathcal{Y}, \mathcal{C}_{\mathcal{Y}})$-valued random variable, where $\mathcal{Y}$ is the space of all Borel measurable functions from $[0,1]$ to $\{0,1\}$. In other words, $Y(s)$ is a Borel measurable function from $[0,1]$ to $\{0,1\}$.

Is this equivalent to define a stochastic process, i.e. a collection of $(\{0,1\}, \mathcal{B}_{\{0,1\}})$-valued random variables

$$
\{X_t \text{ s.t. } t \in [0,1]\}
$$

with $X_t(s)\equiv Y(s)(t)$?

Do we have any restriction on what should be $\mathcal{C}_{\mathcal{Y}}$?

Comment: A stochastic process is the same as a random variable taking function space values, yes. Is that your question or is there more to it?

Comment: I am confused on $\mathcal{C}_{\mathcal{Y}}$:  what is the role of $\mathcal{C}_{\mathcal{Y}}$? Why it does not appear in the definition of a stochastic process? What is the correspondent of the measurability of $Y$ in the definition of a stochastic process?